# Are google tests used only for unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-tests, gtest

The current system I am working on uses google tests for unit tests and pytest for system tests.
Are google tests appropriate only for unit tests? Or can you write system tests with it?

(or are pytest for system tests?)

Comment: Note that just because you encounter some technology choice in the wild does not necessarily mean it was a good choice. The most likely explanation is that the team which made the unit tests liked C++ and the different team which did the system tests liked Python. There could also be historic reasons, like someone creating a prototype in Python and then deciding to port the whole thing to C++ but keep the system tests in Python to confirm that the C++ port was behaving the same way as the Python version.

Comment: You are right. That is why I am asking if google tests can be used for other kind of tests?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that with "google tests" you mean tests written with the [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) C++ testing framework, I'm pretty sure you can use it for system tests, and you can definitely use pytest for unit tests (but for *Python code*).

My guess is that since system tests don't need to match the language the system is written in (by definition they should access it from the outside) and often require a lot of glue code to set up dependencies, someone decided that it was more pleasant to use python for the test code, even for a C++ project. But there might be other reasons as well, why not ask your colleagues?